# In Windows, using the command line, how do you check if a remote port is open?

Tags: windows, networking, tcpip

What is a simple way in Windows to test if traffic gets through to a specific port on a remote machine?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/11207/how-can-i-see-all-active-connections

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I found a hiddem gem the other day from Microsoft that is designed for testing ports:

[Portqry.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310099)

*"Portqry.exe is a command-line utility that you can use to help troubleshoot TCP/IP connectivity issues. Portqry.exe runs on Windows 2000-based computers, on Windows XP-based computers, and on Windows Server 2003-based computers. The utility reports the port status of TCP and UDP ports on a computer that you select. "*

Comment: Note: Attempting to download this from Microsoft returned a page stating the download is "no longer available".

Comment: @dgw Thanks for that .. google shows a new version if you search for `portray" that I'll check out tomorrow

Comment: console version http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=89811747-c74b-4638-a2d5-ac828bdc6983&displaylang=en and ui version: http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/f/4/3f4c6a54-65f0-4164-bdec-a3411ba24d3a/portqryui.exe Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310099/description-of-the-portqry-exe-command-line-utility

Answer (score 150):

Which version of Windows? For Windows 8/Server 2012 and later, the following works in PowerShell:

```
Test-NetConnection 128.159.1.1 -Port 80
```

Some Googling will also turn up alternatives which use the .NET Framework directly (since PowerShell lets you do that) for systems running lower versions of Windows that won't have `Test-NetConnection` available.

If you're not averse to using third-party utilities, [Nmap](http://nmap.org) is also a very good friend to have and it works from the command line.

Comment: .Net method: `$connection = (New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect($target,$port);
If ($connection.Connected) { $connection.Close() }`

Comment: On Win7, that doesn't work :-(

Comment: @samsmith Are you talking about the command in my answer, or the one ST8Z...'s comment? The one in my answer *only* works for Win8/2k12 and higher, and the answer says as much.

Comment: Seems to be Windows 8.1 - Can't seem to find it on Windows 8

Comment: Works great on Windows 10, and I don't need to install any programs or add any features. Thanks! :)

Comment: It is just true for tcp

Answer (score 29):

Use the telnet command to connect to the server on the specified port, and see if a connection can be established.

**Success:**

```
$ telnet my_server 25
220 my_server ESMTP Postfix
```

**Fail:**

```
$ telnet my_server 23632
Connecting To my_server...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23632:
Connect failed
```

Comment: doesn't work for UDP.

Comment: UDP is connectionless..

Comment: Yes telnet uses TCP not UDP. Yes UDP is "connectionless" but PING (Datagram Sockets) also. So if the UDP port to test can give feedback...  As far I remember "connectionless" in TCP/IP does not mean unidirectional but that connection is "not secure" in terms like you might get double answers-packets or not in the right order.

Comment: Telnet has not been available on recent versions of Windows for years - it's now Oct 2022.

Answer (score 8):

Telnet will work for TCP.

Netcat is a better tool for these sorts of things, including UDP, watch out though, some AV softwares consider it an 'evil hacker tool'

Answer (score 2):

Use **[netcat Windows port](https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/)**:

```
>nc -zvv www.google.com 80
www.google.com [108.177.96.103] 80 (http) open
sent 0, rcvd 0
>

>nc -zvv www.google.com 888
www.google.com [108.177.96.147] 888 (?): TIMEDOUT
sent 0, rcvd 0: NOTSOCK
>
```

Answer (score 1):

the following command will list all ports in use on the machine...

```
netstat -a
```

The output contains the protocol, local address, foreign address and current state

[Netstat documentation on microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Question asks about open ports on a *remote* machine, not local.

Answer (score 0):

As @iszi's answer suggested, using the free `nmap` utility downloadable from [nmap.org](https://nmap.org) is a viable option. It could scan for UDP or TCP ports. Example:

```
nmap -n -P0 -p "80,443" microsoft.com duolingo.com
```

where

```
-n           never do DNS resolution
-P0          do not ping to test 'up' state
-p           this is the list of desired ports
"22,80,443"  check in SSH, HTTP and HTTPS in TCP
```

The port list should be inside quotes in Windows because the comma is interpreted as space in the shell.

Result:

```
Nmap scan report for microsoft.com (20.53.203.50)
Host is up (0.21s latency).
Other addresses for microsoft.com (not scanned): 20.81.111.85 20.103.85.33 20.84.181.62 20.112.52.29

PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https

Nmap scan report for duolingo.com (184.72.124.184)
Host is up (0.068s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 2 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 0.62 seconds
```

Port 22 is not open on the tested hosts.

Reference: https://nmap.org/book/man.html

Answer (score -2):

'netstat' is you friend.

Comment: Local machine yes, remote machine no.

Comment: This answer was posted before the edit that specified that it's about a port on remote machine.