# Windows CLI: Built-In Utility to list open Ports in XP / Vista / 7

Tags: networking, windows-7, windows-xp, command-line-interface

I need a utility built into several versions of Windows (XP to Win7 specifically) that can tell me if a particular port is in use. I've found a few different ways for each OS, but I'm looking for a single command that works across all of them.

Comment: by the way: i have seen this thread http://serverfault.com/questions/35218/in-windows-using-the-command-line-how-do-you-check-if-a-port-is-open, but it does not answer my queestion ;-)

Comment: There is not one tool, just a bunch of well-documented commands that have been around forever. What EXACTLY are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to see if a port is in use or not. and it must work on all windows system mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps Netstat? netstat -h will give options.

Comment: Ok, netstat is also an option thanks a lot! Somebody who knows about windows could confirm if it is present in all the windows systems? Thanks

Comment: It's kind of a standard tool from the earlier days of UNIX, so I'd be surprised if it didn't go back to NT 3.x http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat

Comment: `netstat -ab` will dump a list of binaries and their ports.  I'm sure there are gui versions of netstat, but I've no experience with any.

Comment: @dmeu, `netstat` is available on every version of Windows since at least NT4/Win95.

Comment: netstat was also there in 3.5 but prtqry is more specific

Answer (score 3):

If you use `netstat -n` it will tell you the current in use ports. The `-n` tells it not to try to resolve hostnames from IPs.  You could also run it with `-a` to have it TRY to resolve hostnames.

Comment: also very correct! but i can only select one answer as correct one... :-(

Answer (score 3):

```
netstat -bona
```

This will link ports to processes. Very useful if you want to know what process is running on port X.

For easy reviewing I redirect the output to a file

```
netstat -bona > file.txt
```